# Invalid ACPI : Invalid PBLK length [5] during Debian boot

Tags: linux-kernel, acpi

I installed Debian 5.03 Lenny successfully on my machine. I got this error during boot:

> ACPI : invalid PBLK length [5].

After that the Operating System boots properly and starts normally.

What does this error statement mean? Is it safe to work with this installation despite this error?

Answer (score 3):

I used to get this with earlier versions of Ubuntu (which is based on Debian). It turned out to be just that not all BIOS manufacturers had properly implemented the ACPI power management. `PBLK` was some structure in the BIOS and Ubuntu expected it to be correctly formatted.

The only downside for me was that the machine didn't power off completely on its own. It had to be manually cycled when the final shutdown message appeared from the kernel.

I found that, short of recoding a chunk of the Linux distro, there was no way around it.

I've long since tossed out both that motherboard and the early Ubuntu (so I don't actually know if a later Debian would fix it) and no longer have the problem. You might want to consider those possibilities if it worries you.

Comment: The problem is still present as of today, even with newer kernels.

Comment: Got it as well with Debian 8. During install and after when starting my machine. Seems to work normal.

Comment: Still getting this with Debian 11 in 2022. ;)